# Storing knives in knife sheaths

Tags: storage-method, knives

Currently there is a question about [magnetic stripes vs wood blocks](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/storing-knives-wood-block-or-magnetic-stripe), but I was wondering what the general concensus is regarding knife sheaths (like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MDB4UA)) They seem great if you only have a couple knives -- they don't require counter space and aren't at risk of causing accidental harm by falling off a wall. What are the pros and cons of using these instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use these and love them. They really do simplify storage since you can just use any drawer. If you ever needed to travel with your knives (I haven't) they are a great benefit there as well. It's also nice to have your knife in one of these if it's just sitting on your counter while you get everything in place. If you're clumsy and you knock this off the counter you'll only end up with a bruise instead of a trip to the hospital.

The only cons I've found are rather insignificant. You have to occasionally clean them, and you have to go through that one extra step to get to your knife.

Comment: +1 for travel. I prefer my block in the kitchen but I can't stand my relatives' "knives" and always take one of my own in the sheath when we visit.

Comment: I move every 6-9 months so being good for travel is a major plus.

Answer (score 3):

I've used that style of case for years (mine are LamsonSharp ... which look the exact same, so I don't know if Victorinox bought them) ...  but either for travel, or for storing the knives I don't use much (long slicers, which I keep in a drawer).

If the issue is lack of counter space, and keeping knives in a drawer, I'd throw out yet another alternative -- a [drawer knife tray](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000632SX).  They also make [under-cabinet knife blocks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000631ZH), but they always seem to store the knives horizontally.

My mom and aunt (a caterer) just store the knives in cardboard sheaths in a drawer, so you really don't need to go to too much trouble ... I just don't like the sheaths for every-day knives, personally.  The paper ones are better as I can get to 'em one-handed.  The paring knife size one like what you linked to I can pop with my thumb while holding the handle, but the larger ones I need two hands for.

Comment: Another +1 for the under-counter suggestion. I've seen a LOT of knife storage solutions - most of them for commercial kitchens; but I've never seen that type of storage. I prefer stainless wall mounted storage, but these wood blocks are tempting since they don't take up counter or wall space. Thanks @Joe!

Comment: @TMarshall, @Doreene : blah ... I mis-typed ... I meant "under cabinet" not "under counter".  oops.

Comment: no problem! I looked at the product on Amazon (using your link) before I wrote my comment. Somehow I fell into the same trance you were in, and wrote "under-counter" but I meant under-cabinet. It's a good option, and a good suggestion - still +1. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For a long time I just made a sheath for each of my knives from folded cardboard. Worked fine. That is not as secure as the ones you shown, but still allows you to keep the knives in any drawer without dinging them up or presenting a major cut hazard.

But...I like the immediacy of a block or a magnetic mount (used both and don't have a big preference).

Answer (score 1):

Sheaths are great, especially when transporting knives.

Just remember to COMPLETELY dry your blades before putting them in a sheath- otherwise they may rust.  And yes, i've even had a four star heckle, made from stainless steel, get a few rust spots from moisture.

Comment: that's because the word is stain *less*, and not stain *free* :)